# How to configure Jenkins slave as a windows service

Tags: jenkins, windows-services, jnlp, jenkins-agent

[image: Jenkins slave config error]

I have downloaded the jnlp file and while running the jnlp file from the elevated command line i am facing the attached error. please help me with the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if you using command prompt as an administrator.

If it runs after that follow below:-

> "File" => "Install as a service"
>    option from the slave-agent.jnlp GUI.

Comment: yes am running command prompt as an admin as i mentioned in the post it self(elevated) selecting file would be the next step but am not seeing the window where it allows me to select "file", basically its failing to launch the jnlp fail only

Comment: my bad didn't saw "elevated", you can check https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-LaunchslaveagentviaJavaWebStart

Comment: Good luck to run this on a Windows Server Core 1709 (no UI). The command `javaws slave-agent.jnlp` doesn't open anything, thus there is no "file > install as service" option. Ideas how to do this via command line only?

Comment: Do we have any command equivalent to "File" => "Install as a service" option from the slave-agent.jnlp GUI. In my case, after clicking in "Install as a service" only the jenkins-slave.exe and other binary files are getting generated.